# Why am I getting segmentation fault for the pointer here?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting segmentation fault here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("enter the first number: ");
  int a;
  scanf("%d\n",a);
  int *pa = &a;
  printf("enter the second number: ");
  int b;
  scanf("%d\n",b);
  int *pb = &b;
  int *sum = *pa + *pb;
  printf("the sum of the given numbers is %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Tried rearranging the variables but still getting the same error

Comment: For a start, the sum variable should be an integer, not an integer pointer.

Comment: @Subzee You need to write scanf("%d",&a); instead of scanf("%d\n",a);

Comment: now segmentation fault is gone but I'm getting incorrect sum at the output

Comment: Thanks vlad and paxidiablo for the comment

Comment: Please do not edit the question with the suggested fixes applied. Doing so means any answer(s) will no longer make sense!

Comment: Oka I have reverted it back to original

Comment: We have already reverted back for you and you were editing to a wrong version. Please refrain from further edit to the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given both `int a` and `int b`, the respective calls to `scanf` should use the addresses of each variable, e.g., `scanf("%d", &a);`.

Alternatively, use the pointers you have created, e.g., `scanf("%d", pb);`.

See also: [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/2505965)

---

In

```
int *sum = *pa + *pb;
```

`*pa + *pb` is the addition of two integer values, yielding an `int`, which is then converted to a *pointer value* of type `int *` and assigned to `sum`.

In

```
printf("the sum of the given numbers is %d\n", sum);
```

the variadic argument associated with `%d` must be an `int` (or otherwise be subject to an [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) that yields an `int`), but you pass an `int *` instead. This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

To fix both issues, `int *sum` should be `int sum`.